# How to check if subcollection exists in Firestore with Flutter future<bool>

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future

I have a problem with return `true`/`false` statement from Firestore query if some sub-collection exists.

Here is my code:

```
  Future<bool> checkIfCollectionExist(
      String collectionName, String productId) async {
    await _db
        .collection('products')
        .doc(productId)
        .collection(collectionName)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      return value.docs.isNotEmpty;
    });
  }
```

As a result I get Instance of `Future<bool>`, but I need `true`/`false` answer.
What I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Future<bool> checkIfCollectionExist(String collectionName, String productId) async {
  var value = await _db
      .collection('products')
      .doc(productId)
      .collection(collectionName)
      .limit(1)
      .get();
  return value.docs.isNotEmpty;
}
```

Or

```
Future<bool> checkIfCollectionExist(String collectionName, String productId) {
  return _db 
      .collection('products')
      .doc(productId)
      .collection(collectionName)
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    return value.docs.isNotEmpty;
  });
}
```